# Struggling to get my text to display inline

Tags: html

I'm trying to get my `ul` section to display my code on the same line yet it still presents it in a vertical list. I'm new to this and so can't figure out why it won't go on the same line. I've tried `display:inline-block;` and `float:left;` but that hasn't worked.

HTML:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>practice.co.uk</title>
    <link href="main2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>My Webpage</h1>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="page2.html">Page 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <h2>Page 2</h2>
    <p>All the content of Page 2</p>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```css
body nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Have you verified that your page is able to read your css file?

Comment: Should work.. are you sure you posted all the code you have?

Answer (score 0):

You have it right.  Check that the css file is named correctly and that *main2.css* is in the same directory as your html file.

Answer (score 0):

works as expected when put into a snippet - see below. Check the filepath for the stylesheet and typos...

```css
 body nav ul li{
     display:inline-block;
 }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
 <html>
    <head>
        <title>practice.co.uk</title>
        <link href="main2.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>My Webpage</h1>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="page2.html">Page 2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <h2>Page 2</h2>
        <p>All the content of Page 2</p>
    </body>
 </html>
```